# nodejs fetch API - how to setup a global proxy agent for fetch API only on specific URLS?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api, http-proxy

### Question

Is there a way to globally intercept `fetch` requests and conditionally pass an `agent` only on `fetch` requests going to a certain domain? I'm looking for something that would allow me to intercept `fetch` requests made from 3rd party code I rely on

For example something like this? ↓ (*ex: fake/pseudocode*)

```js
https.globalAgent.on('request', (request) => {
  if(request.url.includes('microsoft.com'){
    // pseudo code: idea is to grab the original request & either:
    // 1) clone & cancel the original request & recreate a new one with the agent
    // 2) OR mutate the original request by adding an `agent`
    new Request(request.clone(), {agent: MY_CUSTOM_HTTPS_PROXY_AGENT})
  }
})
```

#### Background Context:

- I am using Nodejs v20+
- I am using a 3rd party library that makes a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) call to the public internet for authentication (ex: microsoft.com)
- Our servers at work are only allowed to make http calls only to our company's domain (*ex: mycompany.com, test.mycompany.com etc*), all calls outside this domain have to be forwarded to a proxy

#### Dilemma

The authentication library I'm using internally makes a `fetch` call to `microsoft.com` which is outside our company's allowed domain list. **As a temporary solution, I forked/copied the auth library and was able to make my call to the auth provider.**

```js
let response = await fetch("some_domain.com", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
  agent: MY_CUSTOM_HTTPS_PROXY_AGENT //  Added this to the fork of the auth library
});
```

Ideally, I don't want to maintain this fork & get out of sync:
In the future I can explore making a PR to the auth library, but I didn't do that since it required changed to 2 other libraries which this auth package depends on & I was short on time

My custom https proxy code which does work. I pass this to `fetch.agent`:

```
import net from 'net';
import tls from 'tls';
import https from 'https';

/*
   @example
   const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent({
     proxy: { host: PROXY_HOST, port: PROXY_PORT },
     key: fs.readFileSync(KEY_PATH),
     cert: fs.readFileSync(CERT_PATH),
     ca: fs.readFileSync(CA_CERT_PATH),
    });
*/
class CustomHttpsProxyAgent extends https.Agent {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.proxy = options.proxy;
    this.key = options.key;
    this.cert = options.cert;
    this.ca = options.ca;
  }

  createConnection(options, callback) {
    const proxySocket = net.connect(this.proxy);

    proxySocket.on('connect', () => {
      const connectRequest = `CONNECT ${options.host}:${options.port} HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n`;
      proxySocket.write(connectRequest);

      proxySocket.once('data', () => {
        const tlsSocket = tls.connect({
          socket: proxySocket,
          servername: options.host,
          key: this.key,
          cert: this.cert,
          ca: this.ca,
        });

        callback(null, tlsSocket);
      });
    });
  }
}

export default CustomHttpsProxyAgent;
```